# In PHP how can we convert infix into prefix and postfix notations?

Tags: php

Are there any available class for these to be downloaded?Where could I use this?Can I use this for passwords or incorporate this for algorithms?

Comment: In generating passwords.

Comment: Just ignore that passwords or algorithms.I don't understand basically the infix into prefix and postfix notations.

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation

Comment: does it have to be in php? goggle finds cones in most languages but not php, would not be hard to convert one.

Comment: You can't change the basics of PHP operator syntax, if that's what you mean. Could you provide some concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Example if a user selects an infix it will convert into prefix and postfix notations.

Comment: Can you provide some ***concrete example***? Actual input and **expected output**?

Answer (score 0):

No. The PHP libraries don't include code to interconvert expressions written using different tree notations. This task is easily done using a simple infix tree walk, outputting the expression wherever you wish in the visit order. You can probably find example programs to do this for elementary computer science courses on the Web.

This has nothing to do with passwords, which should not be generated using simple algorithms such as tree walking.

Sorry for the 8-year delay in answering.